# "parameters.properties.archiveWindowLength must be a TimeSpan/Duration"

Tags: node.js, azure-media-services

I am having the above error whose full description is as follow:

```
Error: Error parameters.properties.archiveWindowLength must be a TimeSpan/Duration. occurred in serializing the payload - {
  "archiveWindowLength": "PT30M",
  "assetName": "asset-OBS"
}.
```

I am using nodeJS, while creating live output from azure it make this error.

My code for this:

```
azureMediaServicesClient.liveOutputs.create(resourceGroup, accountName, liveEventName, liveOutputName, {
            archiveWindowLength : "PT30M",
            assetName : assetName,
 })
```

I have tried to search on this but not found any ans which supports.

- I have tried ms-rest latest 2.5.4.
- followed [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/media/liveoutputs/create).

Comment: can anyone help me is this issue ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66129666/nodecameraview-not-pushing-stream-to-rtmp-url Jason Pan ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The description of archiveWindowLength in the official document and nodejs sdk is different. I guess it may be that nodejs sdk is not updated in time.**

**The latest official document archiveWindowLength is of string type, but it is still moment.duration in nodejs sdk. You can see the screenshot below.**

[image]

**So to modify the program, use `moment.duration`, you need to import `moment` through `const moment = require("moment");`.**

## Your code should like below:

```
const {AzureMediaServices} = require('azure-arm-mediaservices');
const msRestAzure = require('ms-rest-azure');
const msRest = require('ms-rest');
const azureStorage = require('azure-storage');
const moment = require("moment");

// endpoint config
// make sure your URL values end with '/'

const armAadAudience = "https://management.core.windows.net/";
const aadEndpoint = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/";
const armEndpoint = "";
const subscriptionId = "";
const accountName ="";
const location ="";
const aadClientId = "";
const aadSecret ="";
const aadTenantId ="";
const resourceGroup ="";

msRestAzure.loginWithServicePrincipalSecret(aadClientId, aadSecret, aadTenantId, {
environment: {
  activeDirectoryResourceId: armAadAudience,
  resourceManagerEndpointUrl: armEndpoint,
  activeDirectoryEndpointUrl: aadEndpoint
}
  }, async function(err, credentials, subscriptions) {
  if (err) return console.log(err);
  const azureMediaServicesClient = new AzureMediaServices(credentials, subscriptionId, armEndpoint, { noRetryPolicy: true });
  
  try {
    var a=  await azureMediaServicesClient.liveOutputs.create(resourceGroup, accountName, "jasonlive", "jasonliveoutput", {
        
        "archiveWindowLength" : moment.duration("PT30M"),
        "assetName" : "b-mp4-20210108-153238"
    })

    console.log(a)
    
  }
  catch(e){
      console.log(e.message)
  }
});
```

It works for me.

[image]

Comment: thanks a lot, you saved my project...
GOOG experienece on quora....

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66129666/nodecameraview-not-pushing-stream-to-rtmp-url
Jason can you help me in this issue ?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all! Thank you Jason Pan.

Note that there is a brand new Node.js SDK for Media Services here -
https://www.npmjs.com/package/@azure/arm-mediaservices

I have not had time to build any new live streaming samples, but i started to checkin some new encoding samples that shows how to use the newer SDK.
Happy to take any support from the community on samples in this repo! Just let me know which ones you would like to contribute.
https://github.com/Azure-Samples/media-services-v3-node-tutorials/tree/master

I have this branch here right now for working on some new samples. Note only the HelloWorld-listAssets and the StreamFilesSample are updated so far.
https://github.com/Azure-Samples/media-services-v3-node-tutorials/tree/updatedNodeSDK

UPDATES:
I created new samples in Typescript with the latest Nodejs SDK for Media Services. See here
https://github.com/Azure-Samples/media-services-v3-node-tutorials

Comment: i am using this repo.
https://github.com/Azure-Samples/media-services-v3-node-tutorials/tree/master.
nodejs + react-native

Comment: I added new Typescript based samples up here https://github.com/Azure-Samples/media-services-v3-node-tutorials